# Finding the coordinate of P such that OP is perpendicular to the given plane

Tags: vectors

Sketch the plane $4x+2y+3z=24$. FInd the perpendicular distance of the plane $4x+2y=24$ from origin $O$ by first finding co-ordinates of the point $P$ on the plane such that $OP$ is perpendicular to the given plane.

What i tried:
              $OP=(4,2,3)$ thus length of $OP$ is $\sqrt{4^2+2^2+3^3}$ =$\sqrt{29}$
and the length of the plane is $\sqrt{4^2+2^2}$=$\sqrt{20}$

Thus by pythogoras theorem the perpendicular distane of the plane is $\sqrt{29-20}=3$

Thus the perpendicular distance of the plane $4x+2y=24$ from origin $O$ is 3 units. Am i correct?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: We get these types of questions a lot, so it would really help if you could see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I just edited the question and wrote down my solutions

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** A normal vector to a plane defined by $ax+by+cz=d$ is $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: What i tried:
              $OP=(4,2,3)$ thus length of $OP$ is $\sqrt{4^2+2^2+3^3}$ =$\sqrt{29}$
and the length of the plane is $\sqrt{4^2+2^2}$=$\sqrt{20}$

Thus by pythogoras theorem the perpendicular distane of the plane is $\sqrt{29-20}=3$

Thus the perpendicular distance of the plane $4x+2y=24$ from origin $O$ is 3 units. Am i correct?